# How to keep track of how many times a client is calling my EndPoint in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I am building an API in Spring Boot using Kotlin.

Now, in one of my `RestControllers` I want to know how to Keep track of how many times a Client is calling my EndPoint without saving this data in a database

So for example I have a function

```
@PostMapping("/games/new")
fun playGame(@RequestBody gameBody:GameBody){
   val playerId = gameBody.playerId /** I want to know how to keep track of the playerId in memory, something like a cache instead of database, so I can bounce the player if he's playing too much within short periods of time. Because some players would want to use scripts and bots...**/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring boot actuator, that is made for this purpose. See documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot has an inbuilt feature to monitor your server status, health, etc., and I guess this maintaining count is one of them.

Check this link out.

```
https://dzone.com/articles/magic-with-spring-boot-actuator.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve how many times your end-point is called by

1. Add spring *actuator* as a maven dependency

> In essence, Actuator brings production-ready features to our application. Monitoring our app, gathering metrics, understanding traffic, or the state of our database become trivial with this dependency.

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>    
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>  
 </dependency>
```

2. From browsers, please enter

> http://HOST_NAME:PORT/CONTEXT_PATH/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:YOUR_END_POINT